# R lm output - t values and Pr(>|t|) don't correspond

Tags: r, t-test, regression-coefficients

I have just run a lm in R and here is the output:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.182e+01  1.558e+01  -0.759   0.4482    
ht           1.978e-01  1.909e-01   1.036   0.3003    
educ         5.893e-02  7.564e-03   7.791 1.37e-14 ***
age          4.022e-03  2.361e-03   1.704   0.0887 .  
Hb           5.329e-02  1.845e-01   0.289   0.7728    
I(Hb^2)      2.048e-04  6.624e-03   0.031   0.9753    
I(ht^2)     -5.409e-04  5.883e-04  -0.919   0.3581
```

Can someone please explain to me why for this line:

```
I(Hb^2)      2.048e-04  6.624e-03   0.031   0.9753
```

I have a t value of 0.031 and this corresponds to a P value of 0.97? A t value this small is close to 0 meaning that I would expect for it to have a 
probability P('less than' t) close to 50%, maybe 52%? I have made an awful drawing of my understanding here:

[image]

I think my flawed understanding has something to do with the fact that R's output gives P(>|t|)?

Comment: Perhaps it might help to edit your question to say what you think the $p$-value should be especially if you do not understand @peterflom's answer.

Comment: good suggestion, thank you and I have made this edit.

Comment: Hint: graph the interval (on the horizontal axis) corresponding to points whose *sizes* (absolute values) exceed 0.031.  As a check, obviously this interval will not include 0, which rules out your graphic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing you might be missing is that R performs a *two-tailed* t-test - the probability of a test statistic whose value is more extreme than the observed value, i.e. whose *absolute value* is $\geq$ the (absolute value of the) observed value.

The open space in the middle of this curve is the region with $-0.031 < t < 0.031$; the pink and blue areas, which add up to 0.9753, is the region with $|t|>0.031$.

[image]

```
png("tcurve.png")
tx <- seq(from=0.031,to=3.5,length=51)
par(yaxs="i")
curve(dt(x,df=10),from=-3.5,to=3.5,axes=FALSE,ylab="")
axis(side=1)
box(bty="l")
tvals <- dt(tx,df=10)
polygon(c(tx,rev(tx)),c(tvals,rep(0,length(tx))),col="pink")
polygon(c(rev(-tx),-tx),c(rev(tvals),rep(0,length(tx))),col="lightblue")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

That line makes perfect sense. A t value close to 0 corresponds to a high (that is very nonsignificant) p value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see the edits I have made to my question for what I expected the p value should be.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit doesn't help.  PR (>T) describes what a p value is.  What the 0.97 says is that, if the null hypothesis is true, it is still very likely to get a p value this far or farther from 0.  When T = 0.00, the p would be 1.00 (approx).  When t is far from 0, p will be small.

Comment: Sorry, my edit didnt make any sense because stackexchange hid all my text behind my < sign. Not sure why it did this and I have replaced < with 'less than'. I've also added a terrible drawing for why I think the P value should be ~52%. I didnt actually run this t test but thought it should be something a little larger than 50%.

Comment: Nope, close to 1.  That's because it is two sided, as is indicated by the absolute value sign around the t.